# Merge records based on unique ID

Tags: ms-access

I'm certain this has been asked and answered many times before, but unfortunately I don't have the vocabulary yet to find the answer. I'm resorting to asking it in the best way I know how after many hours of searching.

Basically, I have a table of data. Simplified, the fields are:

1. Phone Number
2. Name

Now there are duplicate records for phone numbers, because multiple family members share the same phone number.

Example:

```
555-555-5555 | John Smith
555-555-5555 | Mary Smith
```

Essentially, I want to create a query to merge the duplicate records into a single record with additional fields, like this:

```
555-555-5555 | John Smith | Mary Smith
```

If anyone could help me out, I'd really appreciate it. Hopefully someday I'll be able to return the favour.

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

Comment: The solution above adds all names into a single text field which while it is not what the OP actually asked for is probably a much better solution than adding actual fields. Assuming the adjustment to the parameters of the request is acceptable, using the `ConcatRelated` function shown in the link above is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like:

```
Select PhoneNumber, T1.Name as Name1, T2.Name as Name2, T3.Name as Name3
From MyTable T1
Left Join MyTable T2
On T1.PhoneNumber = T2.PhoneNumber
AND T1.Name <> T2.Name
Left Join MyTable T3
On T1.PhoneNumber = T3.PhoneNumber
AND T1.Name <> T3.Name
AND T2.Name <> T3.Name
```

Comment: Be aware that this is not valid MS Access SQL code. Access requires the use of parenthesis on queries with more than one join. It is also limited to a set number of max records to combine.